# Populate TableView with names of files in documents directory - exception with empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to populate a table view with the file names of the files located in the documents directory but when the button is clicked to show the table view the app crashes saying that the object at index is 0. but there are 14 objects in the array. What could be the fault?

```
@implementation loadDataTVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];

NSString *documentDirectoryPath =         [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
sharedManager.directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]     contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectoryPath error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[sharedManager.directoryContent count]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];

NSString *documentDirectoryPath =   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
sharedManager.directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectoryPath error:NULL];

if (sharedManager.directoryContent.count > 0) {
    return (unsigned long)[sharedManager.directoryContent count];
}
else{
    return 1;
}
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"files" forIndexPath:indexPath];
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];
NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
sharedManager.directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectoryPath error:NULL];

if (sharedManager.directoryContent.count > 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",    [sharedManager.directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"No data Available";

}
    return cell;
}
```

The log:

```
2016-05-18 15:00:44.502 GeoData Grapher[4554:331076] 14
2016-05-18 15:00:47.412 GeoData Grapher[4554:331076] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d2cdd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cd41deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d275885 -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 101
3   GeoData Grapher                     0x000000010a5f07d6 -[DeviceListTVC prepareForSegue:sender:] + 326
4   UIKit                               0x000000010bcc95d5 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 369
5   UIKit                               0x000000010bcc9433 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
6   UIKit                               0x000000010bcc96f7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
7   UIKit                               0x000000010b583a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
8   UIKit                               0x000000010b991067 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 152
9   UIKit                               0x000000010b583a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
10  UIKit                               0x000000010b6f6e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
11  UIKit                               0x000000010b6f7143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
12  UIKit                               0x000000010b6f72be -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 706
13  UIKit                               0x000000010b6f6263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
14  UIKit                               0x000000010b5f699f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
15  UIKit                               0x000000010b5f76d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
16  UIKit                               0x000000010b5a2dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
17  UIKit                               0x000000010b57c553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1f3301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1e922c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1e86e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1e80f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010eb7aad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x000000010b581f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
24  GeoData Grapher                     0x000000010a5f405f main + 111
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011253c92d start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The Segue:

```
   -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
AirconsoleDevice *selectedDevice = self.manager.defaultDevice;
if (selectedPath.section == 0) {
    selectedDevice = self.currentDevices[selectedPath.row];
}
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"session_details"]) {
    AirconsoleSession *session = [[AirconsoleSession alloc] initWithDevice:selectedDevice];
    currentSession = session;
    SessionDetailsVC *sdvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    sdvc.session = session;

} else {
  //   we are presenting the Device Details
    DeviceDetailsTVC *ddvc = [segue.destinationViewController viewControllers][0];
    ddvc.device = selectedDevice;
    }
}
```

Comment: that means your array is nil.  check it by putting breakpoint or using nslog.

Comment: `3   GeoData Grapher                     0x000000010a5f07d6 -[DeviceListTVC prepareForSegue:sender:] + 326` seems to be the problem - what do you do in the `prepareForSegue`in `DeciveListTVC`?

Comment: @Lion the result from the NSlog is displayed at the top (14). Thus the array is not empty

Comment: @luk2302 i will post the code for the segu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

`DeviceDetailsTVC *ddvc = [segue.destinationViewController viewControllers][0];
    ddvc.device = selectedDevice;`

The destination controller is I assume a Navigation controller. And you are accessing the first controller in the stack. 
Check this is actually set up correctly in the Storyboard. Because thats what the line of code expects, but the crash says it cannot find any member in the viewControllers array. 
AFAIK it has nothing to do with the table view and 14 items.

Comment: you were correct, the whole segue was not needed as it was part of the example app provided with the sdk. It was referring to another table view controller that is no longer needed. Thanks for picking up the problem as my knowledge in iOS is a bit limited to say the least.

Comment: Although the debug log is not very beginner/user friendly,  you have the TWO important clues directly in the log.  
1) look at the crash reason -> index 0 is beyond bounds of array. Of course - if array is empty, there isn't a single member with index 0
2) now you need to find WHERE this happens -> look at the stack trace - and go from BOTTOM to TOP....eventually you reach [DeviceListTVC prepareForSegue:sender:] + 326
and right after that the empty array issue happened... so this tells us the issue is localized to the prepareForSegueMethod. Then it's finding the right line and we are done.